# How to move div upward while scrolling downward

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a small html file for myself just to try some new things. so far, I have a header, a background, and a center area for content. it is in the center and the position is set as fixed.

I want to make it so when someone scrolls down, the center area will move up. So there wont be large white-space at the top. Also, when they scroll up, so the center is near the top, it wont go over the header.

I"m sure this can be done with JavaScript. But, I'm not too sure how.

I'm sorry if this is unclear.

Comment: Can you post the pertinent HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using jquery to accomplish this.

You can bind an event listener to the `scroll` event, the handler is passed an `event object` with all the information you need to achieve your desired result (scrolltop, pageX, pageY, etc....)

Once you have captured the scroll event, you can tell where the user scrolled to (how far down), and position your div accordingly.

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using javascript or Jquery (Jquery being the easiest of the two).

***1.) Use arbitrary pixels to define when the div should move.***

```
function scrolling() {
if ($(body).scrollTop() > 120px)
    {
    ....perform div transition...
    }
}
```

**OR**

***2.) Use the position of the target div to define when the div should move.***

```
function scrolling() {
if ($(body).scrollTop() > $("#TargetDiv").offset().top;)
    {
    ....perform div transition...
    }
}
```

If you use the second solution, be sure that you call Jquery and this script **after** the DOM is loaded i.e. after `</body>`. Otherwise it won't be able to define the #TargetDiv.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without use of jquery or javascript, if you are looking to do what I think you are. 
http://jsfiddle.net/wN8c8/ 
by setting your content to a fixed size and setting the content to overflow:auto; 
likewise, you could also set your page background-attachment to fixed, and create the illusion that the text is 'appearing' without the page moving. You can certainly go more in-depth with it using scripting, but it really depends on your intention.

z-index will also allow you to build your page in layers, so that you can determine what shows and what is hidden behind other page elements.

```
body {
   background-color:yellow;
}
#header{
   position:fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height:20px;
   background-color:red;
   z-index:2;
}
#content{
   position:fixed;
   width:80%;
   height:60%;
   background-color:#ddd;
   overflow:auto;
   margin:0px 10%;
   z-index:1;
} 


<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
   This is some content.<br/>
   This is some content.<br/>
   This is some content.<br/>
</div>
```